# Symmetry breaking in near free electron?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry-breaking

In 1D lattice, if we consider a near-free electron model, ie.
$$\hat{H}=-\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(x)\frac{\nabla^2}{2}\hat{\psi}(x)+V(x)\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(x)\hat{\psi}(x)$$
where $V(x)$ is a periodical potential:$V(x+a)=V(x)$ with a the lattice constant.

We know that there'll be a gap between n-th and (n+1)-th band, and the gap is $2|V_{n}|$,
where
$$V_{n}=\int\text{d}x V(x)\text{exp}(-\text{2i}n\pi/a)$$

**My confusion is existence of the gap is related to symmetry breaking? If it is, what symmetry is breaking? If it's not, how to understand the gap?**

Answer (score 1):

Translational symmetry is broken: instead of the invariance to arbitrary translations the system is no invariant only to the translations by a multiple of the lattice vector.

In fact, what we have here is not exactly the symmetry breaking in the same sense as understood in the theory of critical phenomena (although there is some similarity with the [Mott transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mott_transition)) - rather we are dealing with lifting the degeneracy by a lower symmetry perturbation, as, e.g., in case of a magnetic/electric field affecting an atom with spherical symmetry.

*Remark:* Perhaps people working in the field of topological insulators will give a more precise answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question, spontaneous breaking of contious translation al symmetry can also cause gapless goldsone mode. Why breaking of translational symmetry  in the two cases would give different result? Is it because "the gapped one" is not spontaneous symmetry breaking?

Comment: @xiangsun *spontaneous symmetry breaking* occurs in a symmetry system, when its symmetry is lowered. Here the symmetry is explicitly broken by the perturbation. It is like ferromagnetism vs. paramagnetism: the symmetry is broken in both cases, but in the second it is because an external field is applied.

Comment: You can't compare this "symmetry breaking" here to the discussion of broken symmetry in, e.g. an ordered anti-ferromagnetic state. I put symmetry breaking in quotes, because in the context of semiconductors it is not used. What is meant here is that, compared to the free electron, the periodic potential causes the system to exhibit lower symmetry, causing the excitation spectrum to change. If it doesn't wonder you why there are gaps in the excitation specturm of a H atom, then the occurence of a band gap in periodic chrystals should be clear as well.